# Problem read formula excel file with apache poi

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have to read an excel file created by another process.
I work with java and apache poi (4.2, 3.14, ...).
When I try to get the value of cell that contains formula, it does not work.
For sum, the cell formula is =SUM instead of SUM, so it is not working.
I tried to set force recalculation, with a copy of the excel file.
I tried to evaluate all, in cells, ....
Nothing work.
It works if I get the formula cell into a string, and I remove the equal sign.
But when the cell refers to another cell that refers to another cell, it does not work.

When I open the excel file without change anything and I save, it works, but it is not easy (and I am not supposed to do it)

Can you help me to get the formula without equal sign?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The `=` at the front is a UI thing, are you sure the bug isn't in the tool you're getting the file from?